# Ruby on Rails multiple belongs_to associations saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, belongs-to

There is something i don't quite understand in Rails's `belongs_to` concept. Documentation states:

`Adding an object to a collection (has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many) automatically saves that object`

Let's say i have an `Employee` entity:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :city    
  belongs_to :pay_grade
end
```

Will the following code fire three updates and if so is there a better way to do it? :

```
e = Employee.create("John Smith")
Department.find(1) << e
City.find(42) << e
Pay_Grade.find("P-78") << e
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply assign it:

```
e = Employee.new(:name => "John Smith")
e.department = Department.find(1)
e.city = City.find(42)
e.pay_grade = Pay_Grade.where(:name => "P-78")

e.save
```

I changed the `create` to `new` to construct the object before saving it. The constructor takes a hash, not different values. `find` takes only the id and not a string, use `where` on a field instead.

You can also use the following:

```
Employee.create(:name => "John Smith", 
                :department => Department.find(1), 
                :city => City.find(42), 
                :pay_grade => PayGrade.where(:name => "P-78").first
```

Also note that model names should be camel case: `PayGrade` instead of `Pay_Grade`.

Comment: Ok but what would happen if i were to use the *departement.employees << e* form ? Would RoR wait until the last *collection#<<* operation before saving or would it fire one update statement each time?

Comment: `<<` immediately writes to database.